# System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: c#, exception, tfs

I'm getting this exception when running

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\\somenetworklocation\OutputCheck.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _info.ToArray()));
```

Yesterday it worked fine. That line is run by `custum activity` in `tfs build` and it has only testing purposes, whatsoever I need it to work.

1. There is space on a drive it saves to.
2. `TFS Server` has access to that drive.
3. Without any modifications to software I started getting this error.
4. There is available space on the drive it saves to and tfs server.

Update: It started working again after 7 unsuccessful builds. Any idea why this may happen highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is not enough place on the drive where your swap file is. Check your memory consumption. Why do you need the additional array. If you are using .NET4 you can use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\\somenetworklocation\OutputCheck.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _info));`. Maybe you should use a `StreamWriter` and write one line after the other.

Comment: _info is a list<string> refer to 1 and 4 for the space. and check update that i'm asbout to post.

Comment: You have just mentioned that there is enough space on the drive where the file is, not that there is enough space on the drive where your swap file is. Also, if`_info` is a list `ToArray` creates an array with the same size for no reason. Maybe even the list itself is redundant and you can loop whatever the source of the list was to write to the file one line after the other.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, There is more than 30GB of empty space on that drive as well.

Comment: The purpose of this list<string> is to collect data during run of testing binary. This binary is run by custom activity. After all tests are done I do not have a need for that super simple log. The only reason I use this is because adding to List is super clear ans simple so is saving it to a file. If you can share some one liners that will create txt and replace old one and dumb text inside in one line I'm more than happy to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the temporary files on the system which are located in primary drive of that machine.

Comment: done that before posting here, although that never caused any problems